# Need to have a method constantly being called

Tags: java, javafx

I am making Flappy Bird in JavaFX and I have created a method to tell the score. I have tried using a timeline but if I make it call the method too often, it gets very glitchy and if I make it slower, the score increments wrongly. I need a way to have the score method constantly being called without making the game slow and glitchy.

Here is the method for the score:

```
public class Score {

    static int score = 0;
    static boolean incrementScore = false;

    public static int ScoreCount() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        if (FlappyBird.bottomPipes[i].getTranslateX() == Bird.birdView.getTranslateX())
        incrementScore = true;

        if (incrementScore)
        score++;

        incrementScore = false;

        System.out.println(score);

        }
        return score;
     }
}
```

If anyone knows a good way to do this, please let me know.

If you would like to run the program, it can be downloaded [here](http://www.filedropper.com/flappybird_3)

Comment: From the code you have posted, I get the impression that you missed the concepts that are behind JavaFX. I suggest you go back to the basics and take a look how a JavaFX application should be done. For Example the Score can be hold in an `IntegerProperty` which is bound from the UI.

Comment: How would I do that? I have looked at IngegerProperties and im honestly not sure how that could help @hotzst

Answer (score 1):

You should consider calculating your score in every frame. Timeline is not suitable for this purpose. Rather use an `AnimationTimer` like this:

```
new AnimationTimer(){

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        Score.ScoreCount();         
    }

}.start();
```

`handle` will be called in every frame the timer is active.